# activar un datepicker al pulsar sobre un icono y que ponga la fecha en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

tengo el siguiente html puesto con materialize y luego manipulado por css a mi gusto:

```
        <div class="row rfech  "> <!-- fecha nacimiento -->
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input type="input" class="form__field " placeholder=" " name="fec" id="fec" required />
        <label for="fec" class="form__label">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
        <span id="iconocalendario" class="iconocalendario material-icons datepicker">event</span>
      </div>         
    </div>
```

el tema es que cuando le doy al span iconocalendario, activa el datepicker pero no consigo que la fecha seleccionada la ponga en el input.

y una segunda pregunta, no consigo que cambie el formato de la fecha (probé a poner el .datepicker en el input pero siempre sale como año/mes/dia, y necesito que esté al revés... probé con este codigo pero no lo cambia:

```
    <script>
      $(function(){
      $('#iconocalendario').datepicker({
      format:'dd/mm/yyyy'
         });
        });
   </script>
```

este lo he puesto en el header del html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas entonces, es algo como esto:

Acá puedes ver como todo va contenido en el label, además he agregado un ancho más pequeño para que veas el resultado en la página, para que recuerdes sacarlo luego.

El format lo fallas, por querer aplicarlo sobre el icono, y no el input.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' media="screen" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Bootstrap DatePicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap DatePicker -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#txtDate').datepicker({
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="input-group" style="width: 200px;">
        <input id="txtDate" type="text" class="form-control date-input" readonly="readonly" style="width: 200px;"/>
        <label class="input-group-btn" for="txtDate">
          <span class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, el tema es que en el cuadro de texto, no quiero que al pulsar salga el calendario, por si se quiere introducir la fecha manualmente.
Tampoco me sirve el js del formato, ya que uso materialize y no me cambia el formato así...

Comment: La fecha no se puede introducir manualmente... es un readonly

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f6968321dc5c58a9766b239afe1fc1b1.mp4

Comment: Lo único que no puedo resolverte es lo de la fecha, dado que desconozco el uso de materialize

Comment: Pero segun la documentación de este, no es tanta la diferencia...

Comment: la fecha la cambié el formato, ya está bien, el problema es que tenia otro script debajo del todo que me volvia a cambiar el formato :S

Comment: jajajaj nice, perfecto, entonces si mi respuesta te ayudo, recuerda marcarla como correcta.